# Doesn't Nextjs cache the page in development mode?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm under the development progress of nextjs based application and found some fuzzy stuff that's giving bad experience..

I'm just here to ask you whether it's possible to cache pages on nextjs development mode.

Now the problem is that I'm getting white blank screen for some seconds everytime I reload any pages. Changing route works properly and doesn't come with blank white screen.

Only when I reload the page by pressing F5 or clicking reload button, it shows me blank white screen on all kinds of web browsers.  I know I can set the background color of index.html which will overlays during page loading but I don't think it can be the final solution to fix blank white screen.

Are there any way to solve the issue ?

Comment: Do you see the same blank screen when you deploy as well - i.e `npm run build` `npm run start` ?

Comment: Do you have an expensive getServerSideProps or something similar

Comment: As the nextjs documentation describes, the app in production mode caches the pages really well. So in production mode, I can't see blank white screen because it's really fast loading.  It's only development mode when I'm getting blank white screen..
So what I want to know is whether it's possible to cache pages in development mode as well..

Comment: i would also like to know if it is possible to allow caching in dev mode